# Skeletal animation with Unity2D?

Tags: 2d, unity, animation, skeletal-animation

I want my character to aim with the mouse so, arms and head must move following mouse cursor and when the character is stand still it could change its stance a bit to accommodate the arms position. I used to use skeletal systems and in this situation I would use a bone that would move both arms at once but it seems Unity animation only supports tweenings. Can this be done with this system?

On the other hand how would you setup the character to easily make it follow shooting position with head and arms without moving all elements from code? As an example, if I had bones I would have set one parent bone for arms and use it to move both at once, etc. I guess IK and constrains is the way to go.

Comment: When you say "I used to use skeletal systems", do you mean in non-Unity projects? Because Unity does have some 2D skeleton animation tools in the Asset Store. Have you looked at them?

Comment: Yes, like smooth moves. I came across it but have not tried it yet. Anyway, I think my question is api/engine agnostic. In a situation like this that you want to move some parts of the character to make it accommodate to the new firing position (arms, head, etc...) do you ussually do this through code? Or there is an easier way to let the artist setup the skeleton with some ik and constraints and the programmer only has to handle and move the firing position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the excellent Unity Sprites and Bones:
https://github.com/Banbury/UnitySpritesAndBones

Didn't make it to the asset source due to being completely free and open source. It has inverse kinematics and you can use it for this use case.